# Finding the total number of elements in the array in C++

Tags: c++

I need help in calculating the total number of elements stored in an array. For example if I have something like,

```
int a[10] = {1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8};
```

As you can see that the elements of the array are less than the size of the array i.e. 10. Then how do I calculate the total number of elements in the array?

Comment: An array defined as `a[10]` has 10 elements, the fact that you're not assigning all of them doesn't change this fact. Your compiler most likely initializes the rest to 0

Comment: "As you can see that the elements of the array are less than the size of the array" No, I cannot in fact see that, because it is not the case. C++ does not work like that.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Contrary to what you might think, your array has 10 elements, not 8, and most likely your other 2 elements have a value of 0. If you don't resize the array, you can find the number of elements in the array like this. `std::cout << "Array Length= " << (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))<<"\n";`  or  `int arrayLength=0; for (auto i : a) {++arrayLength;}
 std::cout<< "Array Length= " << arrayLength;`

Answer (score 0):

This returns the size of the array which is 10:

`(int)( sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));`

C++ compiler cant tell the difference between actual values and garbage ones.

Comment: This will return `10` and is not what the OP is asking

Comment: That's true, misread. Saw total number of elements in the array and went with it. C++ doesn't work like that.